# Unity Hub "Install failed: Validation failed" message whenever I try to install Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity Hub is missing permissions, and says "user did not agree to the UAC prompt and the process was not started". How can I fix this?

Here are the relevant logs:

```
{"timestamp":"2023-07-19T21:45:43.068Z","level":"info","moduleName":"UnityInstallerWindows","message":"[ 'executing', '\"D:\\\\Program Files\\\\Unity Hub\\\\Unity Hub.exe\"', '-- --winInstaller' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-19T21:45:43.072Z","level":"info","moduleName":"UnityInstallerWindows","message":"[ 'user did not agree to the UAC prompt and the process was not started' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-19T21:45:43.072Z","level":"info","moduleName":"UnityIPCServer","message":"[ 'IPC server Unity-hubInstallServer closed' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-19T21:45:43.072Z","level":"error","moduleName":"UnityInstallerWindows","message":"[ { code: 'User did not grant permission.', message: 'The Hub does not have proper permissions to install Unity.' }, undefined ]"}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-19T21:45:43.072Z","level":"info","moduleName":"Installer: 2022.3.5f1-x86_64","message":"[ 'Validation FAILED.' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-19T21:45:43.072Z","level":"info","moduleName":"Installer: 2022.3.5f1-x86_64","message":"[ 'Exiting from State: Validation. Event: ERROR' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-19T21:45:43.072Z","level":"info","moduleName":"Installer: 2022.3.5f1-x86_64","message":"[ 'Transition to state \"install_failed\" on event \"ERROR\"' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-19T21:45:43.072Z","level":"info","moduleName":"Installation Manager","message":"[ 'Update: install_failed' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-19T21:45:43.072Z","level":"info","moduleName":"Installer: 2022.3.5f1-x86_64","message":"[ 'Entered State: install_failed' ]"}
```

Tried to Install Unity, expected no fail.

Comment: Run as administrator?

Comment: Are you signed into your unity account?

Comment: Am signed in. Have tried running as administrator but no difference. I think something is wrong with the permissions settings for Unity but have given various permissions to no avail

Comment: Strangely the log file says 'user did not agree to the UAC prompt and the process was not started', but it never gave me a UAC prompt to agree to.

Answer (score 3):

[Just found a workaround on reddit that works for me.](https://www.reddit.com/r/unity/comments/14w7i5c/comment/jrqoezp/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

1. In Unity Hub, go to preferences -> installs. Make note of the "Downloads location" (Might have to move it out to a folder you know doesn't get deleted)
2. Outside of the Unity Hub, open a File Explorer, and navigate to the specified "Downloads location"
3. If you haven't already, try to install an editor in the Hub (this will fail)
4. In your File Explorer, there should be an installer in the "Downloads location": https://i.imgur.com/BmVTwCZ.png
5. Double click to open/install and it will install as if it was installed by Unity Hub.

Been having issues with this for so long now and nothing else worked. Manually installing editors did work, but installing addons for them was a bother.

Comment: Hey thanks I've seen this. The issue is that then when I try to connect Unity to Visual Studio Code, it doesn't fully connect and features like IntelliSense don't work. I suspect this is because I didn't install from Unity Hub and the IDE isn't fully recognizing my Unity install. Do you know how to get VS Code to work properly with Unity?

Comment: Hmm, I've only used VSCode and Visual Studio installed with separate installers, and never through the editor. Never had that issue before.

Comment: Make sure you bave the packages for extra featues installed inside the package manager for each unity project you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with an older unity hub version 3.2.0 I guess the problem is with the latest Unity hub they will need to work on this issue. But other than that Unity hub 3.2.0 works just fine.

Comment: Sad that they won't let us access older versions of the hub.